# How to automatically close the execution of the `qemu` after end of process?

Tags: linux, operating-system, qemu, pintos

I want that the `qemu` window after opening and showing the output automatically closes after running `pintOS`

Like when i run the command `pintos -- run alarm-multiple` in `tcsh` shell, qemu displays that *process begins* ,then some `alarm-notifications` and then the *process ends*, but after that the qemu window won't close

I want to exit the window after successful completion of my system call.

Comment: This indicates your `pintOS` doesn't exit properly. Make sure it exits properly i.e. return to it's parent.

Comment: I guess, you haven't read my problem properly. I want the `qemu` window to close automatically, there is no problem in `pintOS`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**UPDATED:**

---

**The new solution**

Here is another better solution that will work for both *`pintos run ...`* and *`make grade`*

add this line to ***devices/shutdown.c*** :: **shutdown_power_off(void)** before the loop.

```
outw( 0x604, 0x0 | 0x2000 );
```

---

**The old Solution**

For the newer versions of qemu you need to run it with the option

```
-device isa-debug-exit
```

Which exits on any write to an IO port, by default it's 0x501

**i.e** in your **pintos** project under the **src/utils** directory you will need to add one line to the **pintos** file in the **run_qemu** subroutine

```
sub run_qemu {
    print "warning: qemu doesn't support --terminal\n"
       if $vga eq 'terminal';
    print "warning: qemu doesn't support jitter\n"
       if defined $jitter;
    my (@cmd) = ('qemu-system-i386');

    push (@cmd, '-device', 'isa-debug-exit'); # <====== add this line
    ..
    ..
    push (@cmd, '-monitor', 'null') if $vga eq 'none' && $debug eq 'none';
    run_command (@cmd);
}
```

and in **shutdown.c** file under the **devices** directory
add this line in the **shutdown_power_off** function after the for loop

```
for (p = s; *p != '\0'; p++)
    outb (0x8900, *p);

outb (0x501, 0x31); // <====== add this line
```

Qemu's exit code is double the value plus one, so there is no way to exit cleanly. Use 0x31 which should result in a qemu exit code of 0x63

finally run pintos with -q option

```
pintos -q run alarm-multiple
```

- Note: this solution will not work for *`make grade`* see the comment below by @pranav3688  for a solution.

Comment: this works in general case, but fails when `make grade` is executed with `qemu` because it needs a clean exit (return code = 0 and not 0x63).... to remedy this, change line 896 of `sub xsystem` of pintos script to `return 0` from `return $?` (which return 0x63 )

Comment: Yes, you are right. Actually, I also found another solution other than the one I wrote, you can just add this line => **outw( 0x604, 0x0 | 0x2000 );**
in /shutdown.c : shutdown_power_off(void) before the loop.
Tell me if this works too, I will update the post for both solutions.

Answer (score 0):

[I recognize the question refers specifically to pintos, but I found myself learning from the answers here, enough to do this under Linux. I thought I would leave this here in case others came to this page for similar reasons...]

I found myself doing this for testing purposes. Here is the [code](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/libs/libcap/libcap.git/tree/kdebug/exit.c) I used (run as root from within the QEMU session):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/io.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define SHUTDOWN_PORT 0x604
#define EXIT_PORT     0x501

static void clean_exit(void) {
    ioperm(SHUTDOWN_PORT, 16, 1);
    outw(0x2000, SHUTDOWN_PORT);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int status;
    if (argc != 2) {
        clean_exit();
    }
    status = atoi(argv[1]);
    printf("exiting with status %d (in three seconds)\n", status);
    sleep(3);
    if (!status) {
        clean_exit();
    }
    ioperm(EXIT_PORT, 8, 1);
    /*
     * status returned is 1+(2*orig_status)
     */
    outb(status-1, EXIT_PORT);
    printf("didn't exit.. did you include '-device isa-debug-exit'"
        " in qemu command?\n");
    exit(1);
}
```

My QEMU environment image is pretty sparse, so I compile it statically as follows:

```
$ gcc -O2 exit.c -o exit --static
```

Usage:

```
   Just exit with status 0    # ./exit
   Same as above              # ./exit 0
   Exit with status 1         # ./exit 1
   Exit with status 1+2*(n-1) # ./exit n
```

For my purposes I only really use `exit`, `exit 0` and `exit 1`.